# Operating Systen three easy pieces - translate stack memory address

Tags: memory, operating-system

I am reading chapter 16 from OSTEP on memory segmentation.

In a example of the section, it translate the 15KB virtual address to physical address:

```
| Segment        | Base      | Size   | Grow Positive   |    
| Code           | 32KB      | 2K     | 1               |  
| Heap           | 34KB      |   2K   | 1               |  
| Stack          | 28KB      |   2K   | 0(negative)     |
```

to translate 15KB virtual address to physical (in the text book):

1. 15KB translate to bit => 11 1100 0000 00000
2. the top 2 bit(11) determined the segment, which is stack.
3. left with 3KB used to obtain correct offset:
   3KB - maximum segment size = 3KB - 4KB = -1KB
4. physical address = 28KB -1KB = 27KB

My question is, in step 4, why is the maximum segment 4KB--isn't it 2KB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in step 4, why is the maximum segment 4KB--isn't it 2KB?

For that part of that book; they're assuming that the hardware uses the highest 2 bits of the (14-bit) virtual address to determine which segment is being used. This leaves you with "14-2 = 12 bits" for the offset within a segment, so it's impossible for the hardware to support segments larger than 4 KiB (because the offset is 12 bits and 2**12 is 4 KiB).

Of course just because the maximum possible size of a segment is 4 KiB doesn't mean you can't have a smaller segment (e.g. a 2 KiB segment). For expand down segments I'd assume that the hardware being described in the book does something like "`if(max_segment_size - offset >= segment_limit) { segmentation_fault(); }`", so if the segment's limit is 2 KiB and "max_segment_size - offset = 4 KiB - 3 KiB = 1 KiB" it'd be fine (no segmentation fault) because 1 KiB less than the segment limit (2 KiB).

*Note: Because no modern CPUs and no modern operating systems use segmentation (and because segmentation works differently on other CPUs - e.g. with segment registers and not "highest N bits select segment"); I'd be tempted to quickly skim through chapter 16 without paying much attention. The important part is "paging" (starting in chapter 18 of the book).*